# Kendo dataItem.set() does not change SOME dataItem values

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

This is baffling. In Kendo's dataSource, dataItem.set() is used to update a record, which is then reflected in the view.

I am not seeing the view updated. This is because the dataItem is never getting changed. So I tore every thing out and now have a simple test button that does nothing but set the dataItem properties:

```
    vm.test = function (dataItem) {

        dataItem.set("AddressLine1","fooz");
        dataItem.set("AddressLine2","fooz");
        dataItem.set("City","fooz");
        dataItem.set("CountryCode","fooz");
        dataItem.set("DaysInTransit", 13);
        dataItem.set("Height", 13);
        dataItem.set("Id", 13);
        dataItem.set("IsMC", true);
        dataItem.set("Length", 13);
        dataItem.set("MasterCartonId", 13);
        dataItem.set("PostalZip","fooz");
        dataItem.set("ShippingCarrier","fooz");
        dataItem.set("ShippingCost", 13);
        dataItem.set("ShippingMethod","fooz");
        dataItem.set("TotalPaid", 13);
        dataItem.set("TrackingNumber", 13);
        dataItem.set("Weight", 13);
        dataItem.set("Width", 13);            

        console.log(dataItem);
    }
```

Here is what the dataItem looked like immediately **before** the set, and then immediately **after**:

```
                 Before                 After           Result

AddressLine1:    "82-1016 Meli Rd"      "fooz"          changed
AddressLine2:    ""                     "fooz"          changed
City:            "Captain cook"         "Captain cook"  no change
CountryCode:     "840"                  "840"           no change
DaysInTransit:   4                      13              changed
Height:          3                      3               no change
Id:              1280                   1280            no change
IsMC:            false                  true            changed
Length:          18                     18              no change
MasterCartonId:  0                      13              changed
PostalZip:       "96704"                "fooz"          changed
ShippingCarrier: "USPS"                 "USPS"          no change
ShippingCost:    11.77                  11.77           no change
ShippingMethod:  "PRIORITY"             "PRIORITY"      no change
TotalPaid:       null                   13              changed
TrackingNumber:  null                   13              changed
Weight:          22                     22              no change
Width:           12                     12              no change
dirty:           false                  true            changed
id:              1280                   1280            no change
```

I could see if they all worked or all failed, but some working and some failing??

And it doesn't seem to be choosy about number versus string or null versus populated.

Stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are using a remote system but in case you are not I recommend you to use the `pushUpdate()` method.

Their differences from kendo documentation:
`The difference between pushUpdate and updating items via their set method is that items updated via set are synced with the remote service.`

Comment: Mystery solved. The fields that were refusing to take a change were the very same fields being displayed (not all of them are displayed) - AND, in the schema, I had all those fields set as editable: false.